# Method runs upon it being addressed as event handler

Tags: python, events, user-interface, tkinter

I'm learning Tkinter and I'm pretty new to programming.

I'm trying to create a window containing a frame, containing a button that deletes the frame containing the button. This is what I've written so far:

```
class Menu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Menu, self).__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_bttn()

    def create_bttn(self):
        self.b1 = Button(self, text ="Instruktioner")
        self.b1["command"] = self.instructions()
        self.b1.pack()

    def instructions(self):
        self.pack_forget()
```

This code seems to create the frame and the button, then delete them again, without me calling the instructions method! I don't understand why and how to avoid this. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate your `Menu` object, it calls to `create_bttn()` and this last method calls `self.instructions()`. You may want to modify some of the following lines:

```
self.b1["command"] = self.instructions()
```

or inside the `instructions` method

```
self.pack_forget()
```

**Edit**

Try replacing this

```
self.b1["command"] = self.instructions()
```

with

```
self.b1["command"] = self.instructions # without ()
```

Comment: Yes, the instructions method is run, but then how can I avoid this while still having instructions as the event handler?

Comment: I don't know much about Tkinter, but try this: `self.b1["command"] = self.instructions` **without ()**

Comment: Please if this answer helped you, mark it as correct answer. So if someone else has the same problem he could see this answer solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Stop calling it yourself.

```
    self.b1["command"] = self.instructions
```